# Alphabetical scrollbar in dojo mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

is it possible to implement an alphabetical scroll bar for a very long list, like the example in link below, in dojox mobile?

[image]

Comment: enrico, if your question has been answered, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to implement it using the following available building blocks:

- Horizontal alphabetic separators in the list: can be implemented as category headers using the "header" parameter of ListItem ([doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mobile/ListItem.html#parameters-from-this-widget)).
- SearchBox (1.8+, [doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mobile/SearchBox.html)): a widget for entering the search criteria (as the one on the top of your screenshot).
- FilteredListMixin (1.9+; [doc](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin), [live sample](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_FilteredList-EdgeToEdgeStoreList-auto-prog.html)): combines and connects list widgets with SearchBox
- LongListMixin (1.9+, [doc](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/LongListMixin), [live sample](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_LongListMixin.html)): highly improves the scrolling performance for long lists.
- The list widget can optionally be backed by a dojo/store ([doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store.html)) using EdgeToEdgeStoreList ([doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList.html), [live sample](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_EdgeToEdgeStoreList.html)).
- The vertical alphabetic index (on the right-side of your screenshot): you would need to implement it, say as a container overlaying the list and with transparent fill color (on phones), or on its right side (on tablets), and using for instance ToolBarButton ([doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton.html)) for each letter. The action of the button-letter would rely on scrollable.scrollIntoView(listItem) ([doc](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/mobile/scrollable.html)) for implementing the automatic scroll when the user touches a given letter.

Hope this helps,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to customize the scrollbar of a ScrollableView, to do that you would have to override and modify the showScrollBar method (and more specifically its createbar internal function) defined in dojox/mobile/scrollable.js.